# Android Chat VoIP with PTT without SIP - multicast, AudioStream, Audiogroup not working

Tags: android, chat, voip, audio-streaming, multicast

my target is an Android app for VoIP chat with PTT (push to talk).
Due to PTT (one android device speaks, the other N Android devices listen), I need multicast address. I think that the right solution is RTP.
For several reasons I cannot use SIP; unfortunatly, all the code examples found on the WEB are done by SIP.
In the following the code I written, but it doesn't work; I tested with 2 devices (one receiving and the other trasmitting) but I cannot hear anything. 
Why? The problem is the multicast IP?
I'll really appreciate  first of all the solution to use my below code; if it is not available, I'll appreciate any suggestion about other solutions/classes/etc... and example codes in order to get my target (chat PTT not using SIP)

MY CODE BELOW: 
Firts the class "RTP_VoIP_Manager", where are implemented the 2 methods for receiving and transmit.
Just after a simple piece of code I use to invoke the 2 methods from the activity.
ThankYou in Advance
Fausto

```
public class RTP_VoIP_Manager
{

private static final String tag="RTP_VoIP_Manager";
private AudioStream audioStream;
private AudioGroup audioGroup;
private Context myContext;
private int localPort;
private InetAddress clientIP;
private InetAddress multicastIPInetAddress;
private static String multicastIP;
private static int multicastPort;

public RTP_VoIP_Manager(String multicastIPArg, int multicastPortArg)   {
    try {
        myContext= BaseActivity.get_myContext();
        clientIP= FunctionsAndParameters.getClientIP();
        audioGroup = new AudioGroup();
        audioGroup.setMode(AudioGroup.MODE_NORMAL);
        audioStream = new AudioStream(clientIP);
        this.multicastIP = multicastIPArg ;
        this.multicastPort = multicastPortArg ;
        this.multicastIPInetAddress =InetAddress.getByName(multicastIP);

    }
    catch (SocketException ex) { Log.e(tag, "Eccezione sul try; SocketException: "+ ex.getMessage(), ex);}
    catch (Exception ex) { Log.e(tag, "Eccezione sul try; Exception: "+ ex.getMessage(), ex); }

}

public void receive_RTP_VoIP( ) {
    try {
        audioStream.join(null); // altrimenti dà errore (java.lang.IllegalStateException: Busy)
        audioStream.setCodec(AudioCodec.PCMU);
        audioStream.setMode(RtpStream.MODE_RECEIVE_ONLY);
        audioStream.associate(multicastIPInetAddress, multicastPort);
        audioStream.join(audioGroup);
        AudioManager Audio =  (AudioManager) myContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        Audio.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        Audio.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
        Audio.setMicrophoneMute(false);
        Log.d(tag, "Avviata Ricezione in chiamata di gruppo - Nome Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        HeaderFragmentManager.setIsTrasmittingInGroupCall(false);
        HeaderFragmentManager.setIsReceivingInGroupCall(true);
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException ex) { Log.e(tag, "Eccezione sul try; UnknownHostException: "+ ex.getMessage(), ex); }
    catch (Exception ex) { Log.e(tag, "Eccezione sul try; Exception: "+ ex.getMessage(), ex); }
}

public void transmit_RTP_VoIP() {
    try {
        audioStream.join(null); // altrimenti dà errore (java.lang.IllegalStateException: Busy)
        audioStream.setCodec(AudioCodec.PCMU);
        audioStream.setMode(RtpStream.MODE_SEND_ONLY);
        audioStream.associate(multicastIPInetAddress, multicastPort);
        audioStream.join(audioGroup);
        AudioManager Audio =  (AudioManager) myContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        Audio.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        Audio.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
        Audio.setMicrophoneMute(true);
        Log.d(tag, "Avviata Trasmissione in chiamata di gruppo - Nome Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        HeaderFragmentManager.setIsTrasmittingInGroupCall(true);
        HeaderFragmentManager.setIsReceivingInGroupCall(false);
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException ex) { Log.e(tag, "Eccezione sul try; UnknownHostException: "+ ex.getMessage(), ex); }
    catch (Exception ex) { Log.e(tag, "Eccezione sul try; Exception: "+ ex.getMessage(), ex); }
}



}
```

INSIDE THE ACTIVITY (for example to trasmit):

```
                    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try { myNativeClass.transmit_RTP_VoIP(); }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            { Log.e(tag,"Avvio nuovo Thread per receive_RTP_VoIP(); exception: " + ex.getMessage(), ex); }
                        }
                    });
                    t.start();
```

Comment: When you crete your RTP_VoIP_Manager object, what address are you passing in as the multicast address?    Are you passing in something like  239.255.0.1?

Comment: Hi,I'm using: multicastIPArg=192.168.1.255 and multicastPortArg=12000

Comment: I was using 192.168.1.255 and Port 12000. After reading your post I tried with another multicast address "224.0.0.10" ; I founded just few minutes ago in a forum that:
multicast addresses have a strict and enforced range.
The multicast addresses are in the range 224.0.0.0 through 239.255.255.255. Unfortunatly it continue to not working. I also tried another small piece of code that simply send messages using multicastsocket: with the previous address (192.168.1.255) it doens'twork , while with the new one (224.0.0.10) it works.  So the address was wrong, but there are other problems

Comment: You need to use a multicast address as you have discovered.  You can try something like 239.255.0.1 or even 239.192.0.1 for your server.  
Note that the typical port for rtp is 5004.   

The clients obviously have to know this address and port as well to subscribe to the multicast group.  

Are both devices on the same LAN for this application?

If you post a more complete version of your code, we can probably help you out better.  For example, someone probably could have easily caught that you were not using a multicast address.

Comment: Before you you start adding all of these audio features, you should build a very simple multicast server application that just sends simple data (like a string) to your multicast clients.  (Essentially a hello world multicast app)
Then you can focus solely on your network code operating correctly before  bloating the code with audio code.

Comment: Hi, first of all Thank you. what is missing of my code is only this intruction I forgot to copy:                    myRTP_VoIP_Manager =new RTP_VoIP_Manager(multicastIP, multicastPort);

Comment: Hi, first of all Thank you. what is missing of my code is only this intruction I forgot to copy:                    myRTP_VoIP_Manager =new RTP_VoIP_Manager("239.192.0.1", 5004); it is located of course inside the activity just before the code I already wrote. I tried with the IP address and the port you wrote but it is not working yet. I already tried as wrote in my previous comment with a simple string, and it worked. But I used to try simply multicastsocket, and not audiogroup, audiostream, etc...

Comment: Just to complete the scenario, in this phase I don't have really a server. I have only 2 android mobiles (1 TX and the other receive), with the same code. The trasmitter has in his own activity the code: myRTP_VoIP_Manager.transmit_RTP_VoIP(); the receceiver has the code: myRTP_VoIP_Manager.receive_RTP_VoIP(); In the future I'll have N androids, 1 Transmit and the other N-1 receive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For who will have the same problem, I'll share what I discovered.  At "http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/AudioStream.html" I found that " the local port is assigned automatically to conform with RFC 3550"; it means that after the port is assigned in one android device, it must be sent to the the other device in some way (I did it manually to test). Then I tried firstly with an unicast IP address (using then the IP address of the device i.e. 192.168.1.10) and it worked. When I simply exchanged the unicast address with a multicast address it didn't work.  So my conclusion is that android.net.RTP doesn't work with multicast. I'll go to study JMF as suggested bt jaybers (thank you!!!) and in case of success I'll share the resul. I'm wondering why in official android site abou the package "android.net.rtp" is written "Provides APIs for RTP (Real-time Transport Protocol), allowing applications to manage on-demand or interactive data streaming. In particular, apps that provide VOIP, push-to-talk, conferencing, and audio streaming can use these APIs to initiate sessions and transmit or receive data streams over any available network." How is possible to do push to talk and conferencing without multicast? Anybody know how is possible to ask question to google about it? I had a look to support but I didn't find anything useful...

Comment: If you found my last comment usefull, please increase my reputation. :-)  Thank you in advance.  Fausto

Comment: thank you for sharing your findings! +1 can you make it finally with the JMF?

Comment: No, at the end of the story I developped a my own protocol, without JMF... it works...

Comment: Good to know that it worked. Mind sharing the experience / code?

Comment: @Vishnu Haridas  my code is made by thousand rows, it is not simple and it is the core of my software, so sorry but I cannot share. PTT is not banal to implement, I spent months before to have a stable system.

Answer (score 1):

The Java Media Framework Guide is located here http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7276-jmf-2.0-fr-doc-oth-JSpec/
Starting on page 139, it gives code examples of streaming RTP audio using multicast.

Comment: Hi, therefore I suppose that there isn't any native android packet to do that, do you confirm?